# While fetching the data from the backend, facing an error stating as unauthorised to access

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api

[image: auth3][image: auth2][image: auth1][image: auth]`enter code here`[image]I wrote API and while fetching the data from the front end, Getting an error as unauthorised access, Could anyone please help me out with this. I am attaching the screenshots.[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCWba.png)[image: error1]
[image]
[image: server main]

Comment: how did you put the API? did you use GET method in your api? if so, is there any authentication procedure that you might be ignoring? I think if you share the related part of the API, we could help you more effectively.

Comment: Added one more screenshot

Comment: That helps, just to double-check, are you using express-jwt' package? or could you please share the content of auth.js. 
Also, have you checked the CORS access for your API?

Comment: yup checked the cors and using express-jwt, i hve attached the code of auth

Answer (score 0):

I believe I just got the issue. Seems like you have a typo in Line 38 of profile.js file. Instead of Authorization (according to the documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt), you misspelled it as Authoristion. I believe it will fix your issue.

Comment: Perfect!! thank you soo much!! It worked.... Got the data from backend.

Comment: Happy to hear that, You can mark this as the answer so that others do not get confused by the comments in this question.